# How to read email of facebook user using Facebook graph api for python-tornado?

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, tornado

I have included 'email' in extended parameters scope. How do I read the email in a tornado object?

My LoginHandler looks like this:

```
class LoginHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler, tornado.auth.FacebookGraphMixin):
    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    def get(self):
        userID = self.get_secure_cookie('user_id')

        if self.get_argument('code', None):
            self.get_authenticated_user(
                redirect_uri='http://localhost:8000/auth/login',
                client_id=self.settings['facebook_api_key'],
                client_secret=self.settings['facebook_secret'],
                code=self.get_argument('code'),
                callback=self.async_callback(self._on_facebook_login))

            return
        elif self.get_secure_cookie('access_token'):
            self.redirect('/')
            return

        self.authorize_redirect(
            redirect_uri='http://localhost:8000/auth/login',
            client_id=self.settings['facebook_api_key'],
            extra_params={'scope': 'email'}
        )

    def _on_facebook_login(self, user):
        if not user:
            self.clear_all_cookies()
            raise tornado.web.HTTPError(500, 'Facebook authentication failed')

        self.set_secure_cookie('user_id', str(user['id']))
        self.set_secure_cookie('user_name', str(user['name']))
        self.set_secure_cookie('access_token', str(user['access_token']))
        self.redirect('/')
```

I need to collect the email in an object and insert it into the database.

Answer (score 2):

I literally had the same problem just a few days ago. Facebook documentation doesn't really help you to use the API. You have to dig around.

Anw, the solution is to make a facebook_request() and get the user profile. In that user profile you can find the email of the user. Put the request in the login callback.

The request would look like this:

```
self.facebook_request("/me", access_token=user["access_token"], callback=self._save_user_profile)
```

You access the user token from the "user" object returned in your _on_facebook_login() callback. Now define another callback called _save_user_profile().

```
def _save_user_profile(self, user):
        if not user:
            raise tornado.web.HTTPError(500, "Facebook authentication failed.")
        try:
            User.objects(email=user['email']).get()
        except DoesNotExist, e:            
            new_u = User()
            new_u.first_name = user['first_name']
            new_u.last_name = user['last_name']
            new_u.email = user['email'] #THIS IS WHAT YOU NEED
            new_u.username = user['username']
            new_u.gender = user['gender']
            new_u.locale = user['locale']
            new_u.fb_id = user['id']
            new_u.save()    
        else:
            #User exists
            pass
```

Comment: Dont you receive a "Exception: Cannot redirect after headers have been written" if you put a redirect? Or you redirect before calling the assynchronous save_user_profile?

Comment: I solved the redirect issue, it was a problem with my code. But now I get an infinite redirect loop with this solution. I am not sure if this is related with some Facebook settings..